# Clicking on suggestion item does not redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete for showing the search result in a dropdown. I have used the `formatResult` function for rendering the custom template. Though I have wrapped the list with anchor tag, when clicked on the certain list or suggestion item, I am not redirected to another page. I have checked the html it generates and it shows what it has to.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    'use strict';
    $('#q').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: "/search/autocomplete/",
    minChars: 2,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    formatResult: function (suggestion, currentValue) {
        return '<a href="'+suggestion.url+'"><li class="list-group-item">'+$.Autocomplete.formatResult(suggestion, currentValue) +'</li></a>';
    },
});
});
```